# how to display a file type related icon in my file search in java?

Tags: java, java-io

When i am searching for a file in windows search bar it will display all the files related with my search term in a list along with its name and icon which is belong to the file type(i.e., for the image file it will show a photo gallery icon on the left side of the file name) and when we click that it will open up related with the file supported application. How do do this stuff in java, i can find the file as per the search term and location but i even want to display the name of the file with icon type?

Comment: Start with [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) and you can use `javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( file )` to get the `Icon` of the `File` which is used by the OS. You can use the `Desktop` open the file using the associated OS program, see [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: thank you very much. one more question, can't we do this in jtable instead of list?